# How to design a position absolute child div placed within overflow hidden div in bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to place a badge (position absolute) on a parent div in a bootstrap carousel. Due to overflow hidden in the .carousel-inner class of bootstrap, the top part of the badge hides.
If I try to remove the overflow hiiden it works, but I need the overflow hidden as well.

Can some one pls help me to find a way out.

Thanks in advance

My Code

http://jsfiddle.net/JPais/jqkg4t1p/6/

[1]: http://ttps://jsfiddle.net/JPais/jqkg4t1p/`fiddle link`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `15px` white top border for the `.item`

And move the `carousel-inner` up with negative margin

```
.carousel-inner>.item {
           border-top: 15px solid #fff;
    }
.carousel-inner {
          margin-top: -15px;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/53u0otns/

Answer (score 0):

Use margin top

```
.txtpic{position: absolute;
    background: #f69165;
    padding: 20px;
    top: -15%;left:15px;
    margin-top:10%}
```

Comment: Thanks for the promt reply. Sorry for the unupdated fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/JPais/jqkg4t1p/6/

Comment: actually i want the badge to peep out, margin-top pushes the badge div in.

Comment: .txtpic{position: absolute;
    background: #f69165;
    padding: 20px;
    top: 10%;left:15px;
    }

Comment: top:1% peeps out the badge :)

Comment: No, due to overflow hidden it cuts the top part.

Comment: are you giving overflow hidden inn class -txtpic

Comment: to the class 'carousel-inner' which is given to the parent

Comment: after adding overflow :hidden to carousel-inner, i have used top:2% and it looks fine...
.txtpic{position: absolute;
    background: #f69165;
    padding: 20px;
    top: 2%;left:15px;
    }

codepen url -http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/JKRrgR  please check it once now